# Hibernate 5: embed-xml attributes are no longer supported and should be removed from mappings

Tags: xml, hibernate, file, mapping

Currently working on migration from Hibernate 4 to Hibernate 5 and having xml mapping configuration files for entities. But one to many relationship is not creating implicit INNER JOIN of related entities when executing select queries with LAZY attribute set to FALSE. Same enties works well in @Annotation based. Issue looks in Hibernate 5. Any one can fix the issue in Xml base configuration.

Below Xml Files:

**1. items.hbm.xml**

```
<class name="Items" table="ITEMS" lazy="false">
    <id name="id" type="long">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="itemId" type="string">
        <column name="item_id"></column>
    </property>
    <property name="itemTotal" type="double">
        <column name="item_total"></column>
    </property>
    <property name="quantity" type="integer">
        <column name="quantity"></column>
    </property>

    <many-to-one name="cart" class="Cart">
        <column name="cart_id" not-null="true"></column>
    </many-to-one>
</class>
```

**2. cart.hbm.xml**

```
<class name="Cart" table="CART" lazy="false">
    <id name="id" type="long">
        <column name="cart_id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="total" type="double">
        <column name="total" />
    </property>
    <property name="name" type="string">
        <column name="name" />
    </property>
</class>
```

Comment: Output in Hibernate 5: